# Tableau's Alert functionality is not sending mails for new Threshold breaking value

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard, tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

I have a sheet in tableau which has orderid and the total fare (like a barchart with orderID and Fare). I want to get alert for each latest orderID whose fare goes above the fare threshold.

I have kept alert frequency " as frequently as possible" and the dashboard is live. In my case tableau sent me alert mail for same orderID which had already broken the threshold(I got same alert mail for each 6 min - then I had to remove "as ferquently as possible" from alert frequency).

Is there any way to get alert for each new orderID?

Comment: Not sure if it will work but set an alert for a change in the *distinct count* of `[orderID]` and then have your report send the most recent `[orderID]` with a *count* of 1.